# How to change the labels for specific levels for the enumerate environment?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Specifically, I want to change the "i" to be "(i)". I tried redefining the "\roman" command to be "(\roman)" without luck ... any thoughts?

Comment: The second level uses (a), not (i). The document class is `article` and I have the following packages: `enumerate, enumitem, units, graphicx, color`. (Among others).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the third level `enumerate` labels to print (i), (ii) and so on, instead of i., ii. by saying in your preamble

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{(\theenumiii)}
```

If more customizations are needed, then it's probably better to have a look at the `enumitem` package.

The first level uses the counter `enumi`, the second level `enumii`, the third level `enumiii` and, not surprisingly, the fourth level uses `enumiv`.

Each counter has a "numeric representation", given by `\theenumi`, `\theenumii`, `\theenumiii` and `\theenumiv`, but also a "label command".

However the `enumitem` package has many bells and whistles for customizing the appearance. *Don't load* both `enumerate` and `enumitem`, preferring the second and more powerful package.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to change the third level of every `enumerate` environment with the help of the the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item{First}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item{First-first}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item{First-first-first}
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for this; I've done it the way egreg suggests; but this doesn't look particularly bad. Unfortunately I can't upvote posts.

Comment: @obU Of course you can _upvote_ both answers. You just cannot _accept_ more than one answer.

Comment: @Thorsten Upvoting requires a reputation of 15.

Comment: @lockstep I didn't think of that. Now he should be able to do it `:)`

Comment: Upvoting apparently requires you to register or login. I don't have an account.

Comment: @obU You shouldn't need to have to register for upvoting. On the other hand, registering doesn't hurt. ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: I can confirm that you definitely *do* need to register to upvote. I've tried to click it several times, and get prevented each time.

Comment: @obU Well, what are you waiting for? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `enumitem` and `enumerate` - they do roughly the same thing (`enumitem` does it better).

Try this (with `enumitem`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
\item Something
\item Something else
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Consult the [`enumitem` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more options.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that I shouldn't use both packages together (I can't upvote you, but I appreciate it).